# Retrieving GET parameters in Salesforce1 Native Application

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, httprequest, lightning

We are currently trying to implement a use-case in wish the trigger is an NFC tag which will then redirect the user to the lightning component related to our use-case, the object ID is contained in the URL and is required in order to make the component work (sent via GET request).

Throughout our attempts, we figured out that:

- The application tries to reach the tab
- Nor the GET parameters are transmitted/computed by our scratch-made script, nor the front or back-end instructions are executed by the component

The URL encoded in the NFC tag has the following:
https://{site_name}.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#{tab_id}?idMeeting=00U580000016Z8oEAE

with:

- {site_name} : the name of our Salesforce instance
- {tab_id} : the ID of the lightning tab
- idMeeting : the parameter we want to send

How can I send GET parameters to a lightning tab in Salesforce1 Native App ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer Tushar.

On the other hand, we managed to fulfill our requirements using the WebApp (not the native one) using the URL hereabove but in an other format:

```
https://{site_name}.lightning.force.com/one/one.app?{get_parameters}#{tab_id}
```

with:

- site_name the name of your domain
- get_parameters the parameters to send via get (i.e. idMeeting=3437598798)
- tab_id the tab_id

As a technical detail, the get parameters were not actually computed after the "#" character because it was recognized as a hash by the browser (and not a parameter of the request).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thats possible for now. As any type of url parameter passing in SF1 and in lightning is not supported. You can't pass the parameter directly.

we can get the parameter in our custom VF pages but in standard functionality it will not make any effect.

So i don't think you can send GET parameters to a lightning tab in Salesforce1 Native App